# Paperclip saving files in the right folder but giving the wrong url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Here is my paperclip initiaizer:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] = :fog
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:fog_credentials] = {:provider => "Local", :local_root => "#{Rails.root}/public/system"}
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:fog_directory] = ""
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:use_timestamp] = false
```

In my model I have:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :logo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png", :url => "/system/cars/logo/:id/:style/:filename"
  validates_attachment_content_type :logo, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/


end
```

But for some reasons when I do:
`Car.last.logo.url` I get: `http://localhost:3000/cars/logo/18/original/7450392a-5e39-11e4-9a87-bea65d182201.png` instead of `http://localhost:3000/system/cars/logo/18/original/7450392a-5e39-11e4-9a87-bea65d182201.png`

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: shot in the dark. Try 'Car.last.logo_url'?

Comment: @Peege151 it returns method_missing